# parallel or async task for functions in elixir from golang and c#

Tags: c#, go, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am learning Elixir with Phoenix. I built a few REST API servers, easily, but there is one more requirement that I need to implement. I need to be able to do parallel or async tasks to call/execute some API from the Backend, and put those results to a JSON response.

This is how I would implement it roughly from Go and C#

```
// Golang
userCount := make(chan int)
usersList := make(chan []Users)

go getAggregateUserCounts(userCount)
go getGetUsersList(usersList)

// do other heavy tasks from here

httpJsonResponse(map[string]interface{}{
    "test":       1,
    "user_count": <-userCount,
    "users_list": <- usersList ,
})



// C# or dotnetcore
public async Task<JsonResult> GetJson(string dbName, string collection)
{
    using(var client = new MongoDBCon())
    {
        // some heavy computations
        var documents = await col.FindAsync<Users>(FilterDefinition<Users>.Empty);
        return Json(new {
              users_count: await documents.ToListAsync().Result.Count,
              users: await users.GetusersList()
        });
    }
}
```

So far, this is what I have for elixir:

```
// Elixir
def start do
  IO.puts "starting.."
  response = %{}
  1..3
  |> Enum.map(fn(id) -> async_get_request(id) end)
  |> Enum.each(
    fn(_) -> 
      item = get_result()
      IO.inspect :"#{item[:user][:id]}"
      IO.inspect item[:user]

      # Map.put(response, :"#{item[:user][:id]}", item[:user])
    end)

  IO.puts "done.."
  IO.inspect response
end

def start2 do
  IO.puts "start2.."
  res = %{
    "item" => Task.async(fn -> IO.puts "weee" end) 
  }
end

def get_request(id) do
  sleep = :rand.uniform(10)
  :timer.sleep(sleep)  
  %{user: %{id: id, sleep: sleep}}
end  

def async_get_request(id) do
  caller = self()
  spawn(fn ->  
    send(caller, {:result, get_request(id)})  
  end)      
end

def get_result do
  receive do
    {:result, result} -> result
  end
end
```

the result is

```
iex(3)> Para.start
starting..
%{id: 2, sleep: 1}
%{id: 3, sleep: 3}
%{id: 1, sleep: 9}
done..
%{}
```

what I want is to have, is

```
%{
 id: 2, {id: 2, sleep: 1},
 id: 3, {id: 3, sleep: 3},
 id: 1, {id: 1, sleep: 9}
 }
```

The above example is just for learning or practice, but for real world, I would prefer adding values to the map by some parallel tasks.

I'm not sure if this is even possible with elixir.

```
 %{
    "users_count": AsyncUsersModule.GetUsersTotal(),
    "users_list": AsyncUsersModule.GetUsersList()
 }
```

and response in json should be

```
{
  "users_count": 10000,
  "users_list": []
}
```

I know I still need lots of practice and reading, I just need some help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is [`Task.yield_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/2) and [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) to treat the result:

```rb
results = 
  1..3
  |> Enum.map(&Task.async(fn -> get_request(&1) end))
  |> Task.yield_many()

for { _, {:ok, value}} <- results, do: IO.inspect(value)
```

Comment: thank you for the interest.. I have tried your suggestion but it is not what I want, or maybe I need to put the value to a map?

Comment: To share the data from different processes you need to introduce an `Agent` and put your data there from your tasks.

Comment: @Hokutosei what exactly does miss for you? The answer given by mudasobwa is correct and all you need.

Comment: After the `Task.yield_many` you can simply continue to manipulate your data - for example using `Enum.reduce` to create a single map.

Comment: sorry, I still can't achieve what I want. after trying what mudasobwa example, I got a list of tasks, and how to get it's values is just another question.. is there any other example I can look on? I am following this example now https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/2